# Getting specific block from UTM CRS, not the zone

Tags: python, coordinate-system, epsg, utm, pyproj

```py
from pyproj import CRS, Proj

import utm 

lat = 10.269558
lon = 25.234

coordsUtm = utm.from_latlon(lat,lon)

crs = CRS.from_dict({'proj': 'utm', 'zone': coordsUtm[2], 'south': False})
```

I want, instead of `'south'`, to add there the block e.g. `'P'` of the conversion.

The converted coordinates are `coordsUtm: (306587.1032364733, 1135747.5454260467, 35, 'P')`

Comment: This might be a helpful reference to be aware of; https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html#find-utm-crs-by-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 3):

As I know, no separate coordinate system is defined for a zone letter in UTM. Therefore, you cannot define a CRS containing a zone letter. As in your example, you have to find the zone letter for a location.